# Object function () { } has no method 'my method'

Tags: javascript, events, callback, closures

i am using a method (`searchTransportation`) for an event callback.

```
exports.searchTransportation = function (items, num, UrlS) {
//...
}

exports.doHotelInsertion = function(items, num, typetransport, UrlS, callback) {
  // (omitted code)


  event.on("STARTWITHAIRSEARCH" + num, searchTransportation ); //!!! causes error

};
```

I tried smth like

```
  event.on("STARTWITHAIRSEARCH" + num, this.searchTransportation(items, num,
          UrlS).bind(this));
```

But this is breaking code and ends up with 
 *Object function () { } has no method 'searchTransportation'*

I understand that the event callback is at the global scope but is there a way to call an existing method?

-- EDIT

this is a bit like this SO question : [Class methods as event handlers in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/229080/class-methods-as-event-handlers-in-javascript) but with a nodejs twist. What s the most elegant way of doing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What is happening is that your `callback` is called before your `event.on` function calls for the `this.searchTransportation.bind(...)`.

So basically you are losing your valid *this* pointer since the function has terminated already. 
*this* pointer is no more referring to a valid object (probably your object goes out of scope and is cleaned from the memory).

You have two options to solve this problem: 
1st one is to create local variables which will be stored till the end of the async call :

```
exports.doHotelInsertion = function(items, num, typetransport, UrlS, callback) {

  var _items = items;
  var _num = num;
  var _UrlS = UrlS; 
  var localthis = this;

  event.on("STARTWITHAIRSEARCH" + num, localthis.searchTransportation(_items, _num, _UrlS));
};
```

2nd and more elegant one would be to bind the variables as parameters to your async call for them to be preserved.

```
exports.doHotelInsertion = function(items, num, typetransport, UrlS, callback) {

  // somestuff
  var localthis = this;

  event.on("STARTWITHAIRSEARCH" + num, localthis.searchTransportation(items, num, UrlS));
};
```

You still have to create a local variable for this but at least for the others it will be tidier.

Answer (score 2):

I am guessing that `searchTransportation` does not return a function, so your bind line should look like this

```
event.on("STARTWITHAIRSEARCH" + num, this.searchTransportation.bind(this, items, num, UrlS));
```

[MDN: `fun.bind(thisArg\[, arg1\[, arg2\[, ...\]\]\])`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind)

Comment: Thanks! but now i get a 'SearchTravelSolution.js: Cannot call method 'bind' of undefined'

Comment: Is this the same object that searchTransportation is in? Need a bit more context here.