# Alternative to .on('error', this.onError.bind(this)) in ES6?

Tags: javascript, node.js, binding, ecmascript-6

```
function Person()
}

function Person.prototype.init() {   
  request('http://google.fr').on('error', this.onError.bind(this));
}

function Person.prototype.onError(error) {
  console.log(error);
}
```

`bind.this` is in `init()` required. What ECMAScript 6 alternatives do I have here to deal with this? Is this the only solution, doesn't seem that I can apply the arrow here.

Comment: Can you please fix your syntax errors? You cannot use dots in a function identifier.

Comment: Why are you binding this method at all? It looks rather static to me.

Comment: possible duplicate of [can i use ES6 fat arrow in class methods?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/31362292/1048572)

Comment: @Bergi Stripped down my example, my actual code access the state of Person.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer your question directly, ES6 doesn't offer any additional functionality that we can use to avoid binding `onError` at its point of invocation. ES6 hasn't done away with the behaviour of JavaScript's execution context.

As a side note, the way that you are declaring your instance methods is illegal and will throw an error. They should be declared as follows:

```
Person.prototype.init = function () {   
    request('http://google.fr').on('error', this.onError.bind(this));
};

Person.prototype.onError = function (error) {
    console.log(error);
};
```

Currently your `onError` method will not suffer from any errors if passed unbound. This is because you don't use `this` inside the `onError` method's body:

```
// Safe unbound method
Person.prototype.onError = function (error) {
    console.log(error);
};

// Unsafe unbound method
Person.prototype.onError = function (error) {
    console.log(this, error);
             // ^^^^
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [fat arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions):

```
request('http://google.fr').on('error', (error) => this.onError(error));
```

Comment: Not sure if this is an improvement.