# How should we get a reference to the object inside of function when using es2015

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Considering the next piece of es2015 code

```
class MyClass{
    constructor () {
        this.title = 'Title';
    }

    update(title) {
        this.title = title;
    }
}
```

what is the best way to make sure that inside of `update` handler I'm  referencing my object with `this`? Currently I have a problem that an external library is calling this `update` not as an object method call but just as a function call and therefore a reference to `this` is not correct. Previously I could write something like `var that = this;` and reference `that` directly in my handler. But what is the best pattern to accomplish the same idea with es2015 syntax?

Comment: In the example that you posted, `this` is always referenced to the instance of `MyClass`...

The library that you're using probably loses the reference, but, this is not clear from your example. please, post a detailed use case...

Comment: Yes, the library I use does  lose this reference, you're right. It basically calls my `update` handler without any context. My question is basically how to avoid that and make a call  to my specific object from my handler without using `this`

Comment: To help you I need more information about your specific case, but, for the moment you should have a look at this article https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind

Comment: Have a look at the possible duplicate [can i use ES6 fat arrow in class methods?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/31362292/1048572)

Comment: Please show us how you are calling the external library.

Comment: I pass my update function as a callback to knockoutjs binding (which is not mine). This binding calls my function later

Comment: @Andrey: Just pass a bound function (`myInstance.update.bind(myInstance)`) or arrow function (`title => myIntance.update(title)`) instead

Answer (score 0):

Since the use case is not totally clear, I recommend having a quick look at [.bind()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind) - basically it lets you pass in a value of 'this'.

Answer (score 0):

`this` in JavaScript is defined by how the function is called.

The only way you can force the issue is to use `Function.prototype.bind`.