# Cannot store arrow function in let/var in React Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, jsx, babeljs

I have a component in react defined by extends *React.Component*. Inside it, along with the render method, is:

```
constructor(props, context) {
    super(props, context);

    this.state = {
        open: false,
    };
}

handleClose = () => { //this works
    this.setState({open: false});
};

handleOpen = () => { //this works
    this.setState({open: true});
};

let empty = () => {}; // does not work, error  Parsing error:      Unexpected token
```

I seem to get an unexpected token error if I prefix any of the arrow functions with let or const. Am I missing something here?

thanks

Comment: *"Am I missing something here?"* It's simply not valid syntax. Not sure what kind of answer you expect...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read [babel documentation](https://babeljs.io/docs/learn-es2015/) about classes. using `let` or `const` is not part of ES6 possible prefix for classes definition

Answer (score 0):

The [ECMA 2015 spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-class-definitions) seems to only allow `methods` and `static methods` in the body of a class definition.

So, in this case, assignment statements are not allowed, hence the `Unexpected token` error from babel.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to use experimental ES7 features and likely only have ES6 enabled (also you cannot prefix let or const in a class). If you're using babel6 it should be simple to switch to the correct plugin. See this answer from basically the same question: [How to use ES6 arrow in class methods?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31362292/can-i-use-es6-fat-arrow-in-class-methods)

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be making use of the [*class properties declartion* proposal](https://github.com/jeffmo/es-class-fields-and-static-properties). The proposed syntax is:

> ```
> class ClassWithoutInits {
>   myProp;
> }
>
> class ClassWithInits {
>   myProp = 42;
> }
> ```

As you can see, no `let` or `const` or `var`. `let empty = () => {};` doesn't work because it is not valid syntax, just like the error message tells you.