# React.js and webpack - why won't it allow var, let, const?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-2017

I have a bit of an issue here that I can't get to the bottom of.

Here's a snippet from my Graph.js file:

```
class Graph extends React.Component {
    @observable newTodoTitle = "";

    s = 40
```

There error in webpack is as follows:

```
ERROR in ./src/components/Graph.js
Module build failed: SyntaxError: Unexpected token (13:6)
2018-01-11T14:56:05.221073500Z 
  11 | 
  12 | 
> 13 |   let s = 40
     |       ^
```

If I remove the "let", it compiles fine!

I'd prefer to keep the var, let, consts, etc. as I want to copy and paste a lot of JavaScript into this file without these errors.

Here's my .babelrc

```
{
  "presets": [
    "react",
    "es2015",
    "stage-1"
  ],
  "plugins": ["transform-decorators-legacy"]
}
```

And here's my webpack.config.js:

```
var path = require('path');
var webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
  devtool: 'eval',
  entry: [
    './src/index'
  ],
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    publicPath: '/static/'
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin()
  ],
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.js', '.jsx']
  },
  module: {
    rules: [{
      test: /\.jsx?$/,
      use: ['babel-loader'],
      include: path.join(__dirname, 'src')
    }]
  }
};
```

Any ideas?

Comment: are you sure the @observable is correctly supported?

Comment: @Anselm thanks so much. Yes, everything compiles fine when I remove the `let s = 40` line

Comment: I may have found my answer... https://stackoverflow.com/a/37840719/395974

Comment: the order of presets is wrong, have es2015 as the top one - not react. it needs to compile down to that from right to left. also, class properties transform plugin missing, though it may be covered by stage-1 as it's now stage-3

Comment: You also may have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22156326/private-properties-in-javascript-es6-classes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to use the [class-fields](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-class-fields) proposal (stage 3 currently) which you will need the [Class properties transform plugin of babel](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-class-properties/) to support this.

As you can see in the docs, your syntax is off.
There is no need for any variable declaration key word for class fields.

Example from the [docs](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-class-fields#field-declarations):

```
class Counter extends HTMLElement {
  x = 0;

  clicked() {
    this.x++;
    window.requestAnimationFrame(this.render.bind(this));
  }

  constructor() {
    super();
    this.onclick = this.clicked.bind(this);
  }

  connectedCallback() { this.render(); }

  render() {
    this.textContent = this.x.toString();
  }
}
```