# Babel configuration to run a redux+react JSBin example. Unexpected token error

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, redux, babeljs

Trying to set up a Babel environment for this JSBin:
https://jsbin.com/taquke/edit?js,output

This is my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "babel",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "main.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-cli": "^6.10.1",
    "babel-plugin-transform-object-rest-spread": "^6.8.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.9.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.11.1"
  }
}
```

This is my .babelrc:

```
    {
      "presets": ["es2015", "react"],
      "plugins": ["transform-object-rest-spread"],
      "env": {
        "development": {

        }
      }
    }
```

+I've defined a file watcher for WebStorm (to babel).

I'm getting this when saving the JS file:
[image: babel error]

Any idea?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [can i use ES6 fat arrow in class methods?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31362292/can-i-use-es6-fat-arrow-in-class-methods)

Comment: There syntax is different, isn't it, there is an equal sign there

Comment: There is an equal sign in yours too, that's what it's crashing on...

Comment: In any case, the answer to that question **is** the answer to your question.. you need the correct babel transform / plugin to handle class arrow properties

Comment: babel-preset-es2015 should cover that.

Comment: You're missing a variable declaration. Use either `const` or `let` before `renderChild`.

Answer (score 0):

[Class properties](https://github.com/jeffmo/es-class-fields-and-static-properties) isn't part of ES2015.

If you would like to define properties directly in a class definition, you should enable `babel-plugin-transform-class-properties` or maybe the whole `babel-preset-stage-1`.