# props is undefined inside my function in es6 class component

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I get Cannot read property 'callToPrayer' of undefined

```
import { adhaan } from './assets/audio.js'

export default class JustPrayClient extends Component {
  constructor (props) {
    super(props)
    // this.props = props   
    this.playSound.bind(this)
  }

  playSound () {
    // console.log(this.props.test)
    this.props.callToPrayer.play() //why is props undefined here?
  }

  render () {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text onPress={this.playSound} style={styles.welcome}>
          Welcome to React Native! {this.props.test}
        </Text>
      </View>
    )
  }
}

const Main = () => <JustPrayClient callToPrayer={adhaan} test='hello' />
```

Does this have something to do with the this context?
If so, I don't know where/how I should bind this...

Comment: You must reassign: `this.playSound = this.playSound.bind(this)`

Comment: Oh stupid me, I was not binding correctly in my constructor! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are **not** binding `playSound` function correctly in the constructor. You need to assign it back to the function like

```
this.playSound = this.playSound.bind(this)
```

Try this and it should fix you problem.
However if you are using webpack and correctly specifying the presets in the module loaders then, binding with arrow functions also functions correclty

```
playSound = () = > {
   console.log(this.props.callToPrayer);
}
```

Also check if `play()` function is getting available to the playSound function once you `console.log()` it and if it is available then you can use it.

Answer (score 1):

you have two choices:

**`.bind` in `constructor`**

```
  constructor (props) {
    super(props);
    this.playSound = this.playSound.bind(this);
  }
```

OR

**use Arrow Function to define `playSound`**

```
  playSound = () => {
    this.props.callToPrayer.play();
  }
```

Comment: Do mean `const playSound = () => { ... }`?

Comment: No. It should be the same way your constructor function and render function looks like (but just use arrow syntax).

Comment: Oh stupid me, I was not binding correctly in my constructor! Thanks a lot!

Comment: @free-soul but you are assigning a variable, you need const, let or var?

Comment: @AndrewLi, no we don't use keywords for defining methods in [ES6 classes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes), except [`static`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/static).

Comment: @free-soul But that's not a method? It's a variable holding an arrow function? It's equivalent to a function expression. You need `const blah = ...`

Comment: Yeah it seems the arrow function thing does not work inside a class like that.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31362292/how-to-use-es6-arrow-in-class-methods

Comment: @free-soul Yes, that's an experimental thing with Babel, but currently you must define it as a variable of the class.

Comment: Yes that's a highly experimental feature (but we still have it if we use presets) to directly put the assignment in the class scope.. But of course you cannot use a keyword `const` or `let` for defining class properties outside constructor (Na! even using `const` inside constructor doesn't become a class property). "There is (intentionally) no direct declarative way to define either prototype data properties (other than methods) class properties, or instance property". More reading http://wiki.ecmascript.org/doku.php?id=strawman:maximally_minimal_classes