# I am confused that should I bind fat arrow function or not in ReactJS?

Tags: reactjs

I am confused that should I bind fat arrow function or not in ReactJS?

normal functions does not work properly without binding but I dont know about fat arrow functions should be binded or not

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use ES6 arrow in class methods?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31362292/how-to-use-es6-arrow-in-class-methods)

Comment: `myFunc.bind(this)` works the same as `() => this.myFunc()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you do not need to bind `this` for arrow functions.  They have the same `this` value as the enclosing context.

```
this.myValue = 5;

const myFunc = () => {
   this.myValue = 10;
}

myFunc();

console.log(this.myValue); // 10
```

See [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#No_binding_of_this) for more details.

Answer (score 1):

If your binding function needs `this` (wich seems mandatory), you effectively need to bind correctly the `this`. The best way (recommanded by the [airbnb eslinter](https://github.com/airbnb/javascript/tree/master/react#methods)) is the fat arrow function.

As an exemple, let's assume I have this component :

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component {

  toBeRunOnSpanClick() {
    this.props.clickHandler();
  }

  render() {return <span onclick={/* What should you use here*/}></span>}
}
```

This won't work :

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component {

  toBeRunOnSpanClick() {
    this.props.clickHandler();
  }

  render() {return <span onclick={this.toBeRunOnSpanClick}></span>}
}
```

The `this` in your toBeRunOnSpanClick function won't be the same than your class. That is the way javascript works.

The good way will be :

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component {

  toBeRunOnSpanClick() {
    this.props.clickHandler();
  }
  // this.toBeRunOnSpanClick.bind(this) will work too but it is way less comprehensive
  render() {return <span onclick={() => {this.toBeRunOnSpanClick()}}></span>}
}
```