# Getter with arrow function syntax

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Is there a JavaScript syntax that lets me do the following more succinctly?

```
class MyClass {
    static get myProp() {
        return 1;
    }
}
```

It is not a huge deal, but I'd like to know if there was something that was like an arrow function that lets me make it just a little more streamlined, something like:

```
class MyClass {
    static get myProp = () => 1;
}
```

I know I could write it like this (though not a safe equivalent):

```
class MyClass {}
MyClass.myProp = 1;
```

Or this more-difficult-to-read and longer alternative:

```
class MyClass {}
Object.define(MyClass, 'myProp', { get: () => 1; });
```

But that feels like an abuse of the `class` syntax.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31362292/how-to-use-es6-arrow-in-class-methods - it seems 'arrow methods' are (still?) an experimental ES7 feature

Comment: Most times when people do `static get myProp() { ...` they don't really need read-only property. It's just idiomatic way to lift `MyClass.myProp = 1` above `constructor` (e.g. useful for AngularJS $inject annotations). There's no alternative except the ones you've listed. `static get myProp = () => 1` is obviously not supported because there's no reason to let it be assigned to anything but function.

Comment: What do you mean by "*though not a safe equivalent*"?

Comment: @le_m: If it's experimental then it's not ES7. ES7 (ES2016) was released last year.

Comment: @FelixKling You are right. I wrote that after reading an old comment of yours "[...] this is an experimental feature for a ES7 proposal." – Felix Kling Jul 11 '15 at 22:23. I should have used past tense. Do you know whether it is still on track to become part of the standard in the future?

Comment: @le_m: Yep, still on track, currently in stage 2: https://github.com/tc39/proposals (Public Class Fields) :) It may or may not get into the spec next year (kinda impossible to know with these proposals).

Comment: @Bergi A real getter is read-only, `MyClass.myProp = 1` is mutable.

Comment: @samanime I could also overwrite the "real getter" if I wanted to, though not with simple assignment. But really, since there is no dynamic computation of the value, you should not use a getter at all - regardless whether with or without arrow functions.

Comment: @Bergi I don't necessarily disagree, but since JavaScript offers no way (at least that I know of) to define a class constant (in a class constant syntax), using a getter is arguably the cleanest method. Additionally, in my particular case, I'm actually returning an object (which could be internally mutable), so returning a new instance of the object is a good idea.

Comment: Would a custom class constructor be an alternative?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a better way to do it. It can be done using Babel Preset for class-transform. 
The preset to get this particular feature is 'preset-stage-2'.

The documentation page of babel for preset-stage-2:
https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/preset-stage-2/

Use Case:
In your **.bablerc** file ad the present.

```
{
  "presets": ["stage-2"]
}
```

**Note**: it is a separate npm module so install it beforehand.

Comment: This is the correct way. This was a question I asked a while back, and we've actually been using this for several months now, though we just use `transform-class-properties` as a plugin without the presets, same thing.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use arrow functions to define class functions within a class declaration. Attempting to do so generates a syntax error.

The following code:

```js
class MyClass {
  static get myVal() {
    console.log(this);
    return 1;
  }

  static get yourVal = () => {
    console.log(this);
    return 2;
  }
}
```

Produces this error:

```
{
  "message": "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token =",
  "filename": "https://stacksnippets.net/js",
  "lineno": 19,
  "colno": 22
}
```

And this code:

```js
class MyClass {
  dogs = (val) => {
   console.log('Bark, bark', val);
  }
}
```

produces this error:

```
{
  "message": "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token =",
  "filename": "https://stacksnippets.net/js",
  "lineno": 14,
  "colno": 12
}
```

This code:

```
class MyClass {}
Object.define(MyClass, 'myProp', { get: () => 1; });
```

Is just the ES5 version to this code:

```
class MyClass {
  static get myProp() { return 1; }
}
```

---

This code:

```
class MyClass {}
MyClass.myProp = 1;
```

Is does attach `myProp` to the prototype of the class and is the equivalent of a static variable. But that value can be changed. So if you want a read only property then you need one of the above setters..

In this code:

```js
class MyClass {
  static get myVal() {
    return 1;
  }
}
MyClass.yourVal = 33;

console.log(MyClass.myVal);
console.log(MyClass.yourVal);
```

We get the output of `1` and `33`. Which is what was expected

Comment: One of the newer syntaxes allows arrow functions in classes, you just have to use a babel transform to do it.

Comment: You said nothing of using Babel in your question. I was stating the rules of ES6. If Babel breaks those rules then it sounds like Babel is broken. I would  appreciate your not marking my answer down since my answer conforms with real ES6 rules

Comment: While it isn't accepted yet, it is an official proposal that is on track for being accepted (stage 3 of 4): https://github.com/tc39/proposal-class-fields. I didn't explicitly specify an ES-level, I just asked for a syntax.

Comment: You used the tag [tag:ecmascript-6]