# avoiding using .bind with ES6 =>

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm new to React and the concepts are still new to me. I'm working on this example and I would like to know if it would be possible to re-write it in another way and avoid using .bind altogether. The goal here is just to minimize the code written required as much as possible!

Full example can be found here:

https://codepen.io/akamali/pen/awvqeM

The component simply render a menu list and when you click on an item it highlight the selected text.

ES5

```
<ul className='languages'>
      {languages.map(function (lang) {
        return (
          <li
            style={lang === this.state.selectedLanguage ? {color: '#d0021b'} : null}
            onClick={this.updateLanguage.bind(null, lang)}
            key={lang}>
              {lang}
          </li>
        )
      }, this)}
    </ul>
```

**ES6 => **

```
<ul className='languages'>
      {languages.map(lang => {
        return (
          <li
            style={lang === this.state.selectedLanguage ? {color: '#d0021b'} : null}
            onClick={this.updateLanguage.bind(null, lang)}
            key={lang}>
              {lang}
          </li>
        )
      },)}
    </ul>
```

Comment: `() => this.updateLanguage(lang)`

Comment: @zerkms that is not preferred as it is less performant than .bind

Comment: @JohnRuddell "as it is less performant than .bind" --- it is implementation specific. The standard does not tell how one should perform. And it would be transpiled anyway.

Comment: if updateLanguage's body has code like `this.x` then binding to null will make it throw NullPointerException, you probably want to bind to `this`

Comment: check this another way of binding (using arrow function): https://codepen.io/anon/pen/VWvxby?editors=0010

Comment: "less code" is not, of itself, a good reason to adopt a particular style.

Comment: @zerkms no as in defining inline functions generally has a performance impact on your code (when in the render) https://github.com/yannickcr/eslint-plugin-react/blob/master/docs/rules/jsx-no-bind.md

Comment: @JohnRuddell your last message which I am agree with does not correlate with what you said initially: "as it is less performant than .bind"

Comment: @zerkms .bind is more performant than an inline arrow function. Let me find the tests that prove it :). Someone ran time tests to verify.

Comment: @JohnRuddell performance of the new ES201x features improve from release to release.

Comment: @zerkms that is true. It could be different :) I need to look at any differences of when .bind is used or when an inline arrow is used. Before they were compiled differently.. but that could have changed since now.  Good point!

Answer (score 2):

What you want to do is make each item a component, this way there is no inline binding in your render

```
{languages.map(lang => <ListItem lang={lang} updateLanguage={this.updateLanguage} selected={lang === this.state.selectedLanguage } />)}
```

and then your list item handles the click with a single bound instance.

```
class ListItem extends Component {
    handleClick = () => {
        this.props.updateLanguage(this.props.lang);
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <li 
                style={this.props.selected ? {color: '#d0021b'} : null}
                onClick={this.handleClick}
            >
                {this.props.lang}
            </li>
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: You also need to bind `this.handleClick` in the constructor.

Comment: @zerkms no because handleClick is an arrow function. assuming your compiler accepts the arrow on function declaration. Thats how I write all of my functions I want bound in a react class

Comment: Oh, I did not know that, thanks. It's not standardised yet though.

Comment: @zerkms yea, if you are using babel to compile then [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31362350/2733506) would help someone get setup. I like typescript and with typescript using the ts-loader in webpack the fat arrow functions are standardized!

Comment: It's class member variables https://tc39.github.io/proposal-class-public-fields. Fat arrows are there from ES2015.

Comment: @John Ruddell I'm not sure if you could put a working example in codepen or pastbin, as I'm still confused with your answer. Thanks

Comment: @user2398069 what part of my answer is confusing? i can help explain it better if you can let me know :)

Comment: @user2398069 here is your codepen updated with my answer. https://codepen.io/anon/pen/qjOeyP

Answer (score -1):

First you bind to `null`, if `updateLanguage` has code like this :

```
updateLanguage(lang){
    this.x;
}
```

It will throw a null pointer exception, you probably wanted to bind to `this`.

Now why would anyone bind ? to explain this look at example definition of `updateLanguage` :

```
updateLanguage(lang){
    this.setState({language: lang});
}
```

In this function we want `this` to be the React component as we're using `setState` here.

But when you register events with this function then whoever triggers the event will be `this` inside updateLanguage's body, so `this` above will be e.g. `li` which doesn't have `setState`.

By binding you make sure `this` will be the component, anyway you can get rid of binding by doing this :

```
<li
    onClick={() => this.updateLanguage(lang)}            
</li>
```

Because when registering it as an arrow function we're actually registering a closure which closes over `this` which is the component here, I leave it to you whether you like this style or not.

Another way is to use propery syntax initializer e.g. :

```
updateLanguage : (lang) => {
}
```

And then

```
  <li
      onClick={this.updateLanguage(lang)}            
  </li>
```

These ways are mentioned in React Docs by the way, see here : 
https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/handling-events.html

Comment: would you be able to put a working example with your suggestion? I would appreciate that! Thanks