# Why are there different syntax of methods inside extending React.Component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I notice that inside `class ExampleComponent extends React.Component {...}` there are different ways of defining methods, with the former being a declaration for methods that is part of React and the latter being expressions for your own methods. Why is this? Why aren't they both in the same format?

```
  componentDidMount() {
    ...
  }
```

vs.

```
  myMethod = () => {
    ...
  }
```

Comment: because... they both do the same thing? one just happens to be an arrow function. It may or may not need to be, depending on how it is called.

Comment: @KevinB No, they're not the same?

Comment: One is a valid ES6 method definition, the other is not. [It's an experimental syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31362292/how-to-use-arrow-functions-public-class-fields-as-class-methods) and should better go inside the constructor.

Answer (score 1):

This one goes to prototype

```
fnProto() {

}
```

This one is experimental and goes directly to instance having `this` always refering to the instance.

```
fnInstance = () => {}
```

Translating to ES5

```
class Cmp {
 fnProto() {
   console.log('goes to proto')
 }

  fnInstance = () => {
    console.log('goes to instance')
  }
}
```

Will be roughly equivalent to

```
function Cmp() {
   this.fnInstance = (function() {
      console.log('goes to instance')
   }).bind(this)
}

Cmp.prototype.fnProto = function() {
   console.log('goes to proto')
}
```

Answer (score -1):

When you have

```
componentDidMount() {
    ...
  }
```

it is a lifecycle function and `this` inside it is automatically bound by default to the React Component context.

However when you define your own function, `this` inside it will refer to the content of the function itself. However if you define it using an `arrow function` like

```
myMethod = () => {
    ...
  }
```

`this` keyword inside it will refer to the parent context which in this case is the React Component context.

Check this article on **[Arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)**

Comment: What does "automatically bound by default to the React Component context" mean? *"this inside it will refer to the content of the function itself."* What is the "content" of a function? `this` certainly does not refer to that.

Comment: @FelixKling, I suppose you are experienced enough to understand that, `content` was a typo.