# Arrow vs classic method in ES6 class

Tags: javascript, jsx, arrow-functions, ecmascript-next, class-fields

Is there any reason to write classic syntax of ES6 methods?

```
class MyClass {

    myMethod() {
        this.myVariable++;
    }

}
```

When I use `myMethod()` as callback on some event, I must write something like this (in JSX):

```
// Anonymous function.
onClick={() => { this.myMethod(); }}

// Or bind this.
onClick={this.myMethod.bind(this)}
```

But if I declare method as arrow function:

```
class MyClass {

    myMethod = () => {
        this.myVariable++;
    }

}
```

than I can write just (in JSX):

```
onClick={this.myMethod}
```

Comment: All i get is a syntax error.

Comment: I'm not sure it works normally, but with Babel (Webpack) it works.

Comment: Those extraneous `{ }` are erroneous.

Comment: Sorry, onClick={...} is in JSX, no HTML.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use arrow functions (public class fields) as class methods?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31362292/1048572)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The feature you are using is not part of ES6. It's the [*class fields* proposal](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-class-fields). It allows you to initialize instance properties without having to write a constructor. I.e. your code:

```
class MyClass {

    myMethod = () => {
        this.myVariable++;
    }

}
```

is exactly the same as

```
class MyClass {

    constructor() {
        this.myMethod = () => {
            this.myVariable++;
        };
    }

}
```

And this also shows you what the difference is between a *normal* class method an a method created via a class field:

- A normal method is shared between all instances of the class (it is defined on the prototype)
- A "class field method" is created per instance

So all the same as reasons as presented in [Use of 'prototype' vs. 'this' in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/310870/218196) apply, but in short:

- Use "class field methods" if you need a method per instance. Such is the case for event handlers that need to access the current instance. Access to `this` also only works if you are using an arrow function.
- Use normal class methods in all other cases.