# What is the difference between class method vs. class field function vs. class field arrow function?

Tags: javascript, typescript, class, class-method, class-fields

What is the difference between class method, class property which is a function, and class property which is an arrow function? Does the `this` keyword behave differently in the different variants of the method?

```js
class Greeter {
  constructor() {
    this.greet();
    this.greet2();
    this.greet3();
  }

  greet() {
    console.log('greet1', this);
  }

  greet2 = () => {
    console.log('greet2', this);
  }

  greet3 = function() {
    console.log('greet3', this);
  }
}
      
let bla = new Greeter();
```

This is the resulting JavaScript when transpiled from TypeScript.

```js
var Greeter = /** @class */ (function () {
function Greeter() {
    var _this = this;
    this.greet2 = function () {
        console.log('greet2', _this);
    };
    this.greet3 = function () {
        console.log('greet3', this);
    };
    this.greet();
    this.greet2();
    this.greet3();
}
Greeter.prototype.greet = function () {
    console.log('greet1', this);
};
return Greeter;
}());
var bla = new Greeter();
```

My TypeScript version is 3.4.5.

Comment: When I compile it on my computer - there are no errors (tsc ./test.ts). I can get the compiled javascript and run it in the browser console with no problems.

Comment: @Combine Well if you look at the compilation result, the differences ought to be obvious.

Comment: @Bergi I would not ask this question if the answer was clear to me.

Comment: @Combine Did you look at the compiler output? Can you post it?

Comment: I just added it to the question @Bergi

Comment: Great! Now you can see that [`greet` is put on the prototype but `greet3` is put on each instance in the constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/q/310870/1048572), and that both use [dynamic `this`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3127429/1048572) while [`greet2` is an arrow function with lexical this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34696686/1048572).

Comment: Related: [How to use arrow functions (public class fields) as class methods?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31362292/1048572)

Comment: Since this is now valid JS syntax, the question applies to vanilla JS as well as TS.

Comment: Related: [Arrow vs classic method in ES6 class](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45896230/1048572)

Answer (score 35):

There are differences between all 3 versions. This differences are in 3 areas:

1. Who is `this` at runtime
2. Where the function is assigned
3. What is the type of `this` in typescript.

Lets start with where they work just the same. Consider this class, with a class field:

```
class Greeter {
  constructor(private x: string) {
  }
  greet() {
    console.log('greet1', this.x);
  }

  greet2 = () => {
    console.log('greet2', this.x);
  }

  greet3 = function () {    
    // this is typed as any 
    console.log('greet3', this.x);
  }
}

let bla = new Greeter(" me");
```

With this class all 3 function calls will print as expected: `'greet*  me'` when invoked on `bla`

```
bla.greet()
bla.greet2()
bla.greet3()
```

**Who is this at runtime**

Arrow functions capture `this` from the declaration context, so `this` in `greet2` is always guaranteed  to be the class instance that created this function. The other versions (the method and function) make no such guarantees.

So in this code not all 3 print the same text:

```
function call(fn: () => void) {
  fn();
}

call(bla.greet) // greet1 undefined 
call(bla.greet2) //greet2 me
call(bla.greet3) // greet3 undefined
```

This is particularly important when passing the function as an event handler to another component.

**Where the function is assigned**

Class methods (such as `greet`) are assigned on the prototype, field initializations (such as `greet2` and `greet3`) are assigned in the constructor. This means that `greet2` and `greet3` will have a larger memory footprint as they require an allocation of a fresh closure each time `Greeter` is instantiated.

**What is the type of this in typescript.**

Typescript will type `this` as an instance of `Greeter` in both the method (`greet`) and the arrow function (`greet2`) but will type `this` as any in `greet3`. This will make it an error if you try to use `this` in `greet3` under `noImplictAny`

**When to use them**

1. Use the method syntax if this function will not be passed as an event handler to another component (unless you use `bind` or something else to ensure `this` remains the instance of the class)
2. Use arrow function syntax when your function will be passed around to other components and you need access to `this` inside the function.
3. Can't really think of a good use case for this, generally avoid.

Answer (score 7):

#### `this` keyword difference:

In the above all three have same `this` but you will see the difference when you will pass the method to another functions.

```js
class Greeter {
  constructor() {
  }
  greet() {
    console.log(this);
  }

  greet2 = () => {
    console.log(this);
  }

  greet3 = function() {
    console.log(this);
  }
}


let bla = new Greeter();
function wrapper(f){
  f();
}
wrapper(bla.greet) //undefined
wrapper(bla.greet2) //Greeter 
wrapper(bla.greet3) //undefined
```

But there is another difference that the first method is on the `prototype` of `class` while other two are not. They are the method of instance of object.

```js
class Greeter {
  constructor() {
  }
  greet() {
    console.log('greet1', this);
  }

  greet2 = () => {
    console.log('greet2', this);
  }

  greet3 = function() {
    console.log('greet3', this);
  }
}

let bla = new Greeter();
console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyNames(Greeter.prototype))
```

> If I have in the class -> `str = "my string";` and in all the 3 methods I can say `console.log(this.str)` and it outputs the "my string". But I wonder - is this really actually the same thing

No they are not same things. As I mentioned that `greet2` and `greet3` will not be on `Greeter.prototype` instead they will be on the instance itself. It mean that if you create `1000` instances of `Greeter` their will be 1000 different method(`greet2` and `greet3`) stored in memory for 1000 different instances. But there will a single `greet` method for all the instances.

See the below snippet with two instances of `Greeter()`

Comment: If I have in the class -> str = "my string";  and in all the 3 methods I can say console.log(this.str) and it outputs the "my string". But I wonder - is 'this' really actually The same thing in all 3 variants of the method ?

Comment: @Combine I have added more explanation in the end of answer. Please check it.

Comment: What do you mean there is no difference regarding `this`, arrow functions capture `this` regular functions don't, huge implications if you pass the method in a function variable ..

Comment: It still says "*all three have same this*" which is evidently incorrect?

Comment: @Bergi I mean in the given code when the OP is calling the function from `constructor`  all three have same `this`