# Confused behaviour in javascript when using arrow function reference vs. inline arrow function

Tags: javascript, function

Since `this` in arrow functions refers to lexical context, it is expected that the following code would log the object itself:

```
const arrow = () => {
  console.log(this);
};
const object = {
  render() {
    setTimeout(arrow, 1000);
  },
};
object.render();
```

However it actually logs the `global` object. This is confusing to me because
when I use an inline arrow function, it works fine and logs the `obj`:

```
const object = {
  render() {
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log(this);
    }, 1000);
  },
};
object.render();
```

With an inline version of the same arrow function the code logs the object itself, which is exactly what I want. I'm really confused about why this happens. They are both arrow functions, aren't they?

***Update:** Thanks for the answers! So `this` in arrow functions keeps the reference when they were defined. But what about `this` in a class? e.g.,

```
class MyClass {
    handleChange = () => {
      console.log(this);
    };
    render() {
      setTimeout(this.handleChange, 1000);
    }
  }
  const myclass = new MyClass();
  myclass.render();
```

In this case, `this` in `handleChange` refers to the object `myclass`. But if it keeps the original reference, shouldn't it refers to the `global` when it was defined?

Comment: with arrow functions, think of it like this: `this` is unchanging. Whatever `this` means where you define the function, `this` will always mean the same thing inside the function whenever you call it.

Comment: Exactly, lexical context. `this` will be whatever `this` was where `const arrow = () => ...` was *defined*.

Comment: `class .. { foo = () => ... }` creates bound instance methods: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45898085/476

Comment: Thanks. It makes so much sense to me now.