# How to create CallBack method to get value from another JS?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-ios

I have create `CustomDatePicker.JS` file for datePicker, for Android use the `DatePickerAndroid` and for ios use `DatePickerIOS`, and its use in my another `Profile.js` file. I use like below.

```
<CustomDatePicker ref='modal'></CustomDatePicker>
```

Now whenever will select the date, `CustomDatePicker.JS` class get the value but I want to the date value in `Profile.js`. So how can get date value in profile.

`CustomDatePicker.JS` : Here Will get date and time log.
`Profile.js` : Want to date which is selected on CustomDatePicker.

I hope, You are underStand...

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In your `Profile.js`, i.e `Profile component` you can pass some callback fn as props like,

```
<CustomDatePicker 
  mode="date"
  onDateChange={date => this.onDateChange(date)}
  ref='modal'>
</CustomDatePicker>
```

In you `CustomDatePicker.js`, i.e `CustomDatePicker component` where you have defined `DatePickerIOS`, you can use those props.

```
<DatePickerIOS
   {...this.props}
/>
```

Comment: Yes, It's only for iOS but Android. Can we create Common for both iOS and android like onDateChange type.

Comment: @KiritModi, I have not used android, but I think, you can use the same file and return which component to render based on the Platform.OS.

Comment: In my code, I have both android and iOS use and also get date but want to one function like onDateChange type. so that can easily get date from the function.

Comment: @KiritModi I am not aware of andriod implementation, but hope this node module might help: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-datepicker