# React Webpack "unexpected token" named arrow function

Tags: reactjs, webpack, ecmascript-6

I have set up react fullstack environment with webpack-middleware. I have some es6 syntax in my code but I get error while state without constructor or named arrow function. For example, I want to use semantic-ui for react sort table:
https://react.semantic-ui.com/collections/table#table-example-sortable
And while compiling I get this error:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GbBVP.png)

I thought it is because of wrong webpack setup I attached it below.

```
const webpack = require('webpack');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
  entry: './client/index.js',
  output: {
    path: '/',
    filename: 'bundle.js'
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        use: 'babel-loader',
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/
      }
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: 'client/index.html'
    })
  ]
};
```

.babelrc

```
{
  "presets": ["env", "react", "es2015"]
}
```

Comment: Can you include the code (arrow function) that is causing the issue?

Comment: Duplicate of [How to use arrow functions (public class fields) as class methods?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31362292/218196)

Comment: The syntax you are using is not ES6.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're trying to use class properties, which are currently stage 3 as part of the [Class fields proposal](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-class-fields). To be able to use them today, you have to install [`babel-plugin-transform-class-properties`](https://github.com/babel/babel/tree/master/packages/babel-plugin-transform-class-properties).

```
npm install --save-dev babel-plugin-transform-class-properties
```

And add it to your plugins in `.babelrc`.

```
{
  "presets": ["env", "react"],
  "plugins": ["transform-class-properties"]
}
```

I also removed the `es2015` preset since it has been deprecated in favour of `babel-preset-env`, which contains everything `es2015` does and more.

Comment: These aren't class fields, though, they're "fat arrow"-styled methods?

Comment: They are class properties, you just happen to assign an arrow function to it. You could have just as well used `hideFixedMenu = true` or anything else in place of `true`. See also the [Example shown by `babel-plugin-transform-class-properties`](https://github.com/babel/babel/tree/master/packages/babel-plugin-transform-class-properties#example).

Comment: Thank you all for quick help. You are great.