# Unexpected Token switching from create-react-app to babel/webpack setup

Tags: reactjs, webpack, babeljs

I am just learning to switch from `create-react-app` to `babel` and `webpack`. I used a set up which worked for the tutorial code, after I got it to work I tried it on my app, but I got an error at :

```
Module build failed: SyntaxError: C:/App/smodin-post-writer-no-cra/src/components/UserSettings.js: Unexpected token (7:10)

_confirm = async () => {
     |              ^
  73 |         const { name, email, password } = this.state
  74 |         if (this.state.login) {
  75 |             const result = await this.props.signinUserMutation({
```

My presets are `"presets" : ["es2015", "react"]`. All dependencies should be installed correctly.

**Any ideas why I'm getting this error?**

Note: using `npm run eject` for the app and running it that way works, but I get a ton I don't need.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use arrow functions (public class fields) as class methods?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31362292/how-to-use-arrow-functions-public-class-fields-as-class-methods)

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: @Timo sorry totally didn't realize that didn't copy, just added it.

Comment: @Loganfsmyth, I don't see how it is a duplicate of that question, if it is I can take it down.

Comment: As the answer says, that syntax is experimental so your two presets aren't enough to cover it.

Comment: @loganfsmyth ok I now understand where you're coming from, I believe you are correct, I will address this, thank you! Is it better to take this question down or leave it up and answer it?

Comment: Generally best to close it as a duplicate. That way people searching could still find it and get redirected to the other answer. If you delete it, it'll just be gone.