# Cant use arrow function inside JS Class

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, es6-class, arrow-functions

I am trying to use  arrow function (method) inside JS Class, using new syntax but i get error "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token = "

```
class Images{
constructor(elements){
    this.elements = elements;
}
 nextClick =()=>{
    //some code
}};
```

Everything else is working fine. Arrow functions outside the class are working perfect.

Comment: Put them inside the constructor.

Comment: what do you mean ? how can i put method inside constructor?

Comment: [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31368520/1048572)

Comment: Why are you trying to use an arrow function? What `this` value are you trying to capture?

Comment: in the constructor this.elements is an array of  img elements, but nextClick function works when button is clicked, so  inside function THIS is the button, so i cant use this.elements