# ES6 Arrow Functions, Syntax Error

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, es6-class, arrow-functions

I have the following JS class

```js
class Tree {   

    constructor(rootNode) {
        this._rootNode = rootNode;
        rootNode.makeRoot();
    }
      
    getRoot() {
        return this._rootNode;
    }

    findNodeWithID(id) {
       return this.findNode(this._rootNode, id);
    }

    findNode = (node, id) => {
        if(node.id === id) {
            return node;
        } else {
            node.getChildren().forEach(child => {
                  this.findNode(child, id);
            });
        } 
        return null;
    }
}
```

I have two issues:

1. This won't compile, gives an error

   findNode = (node, id) => {
                ^
   SyntaxError: Unexpected token =
2. When I change it to a regular function

```js
findNode = (node, id) => {
       ...
    }
```

the method findNodeWithID doesn't work. Any idea why?

Comment: There's still the =, it's not a regular function, you're trying to assign something. Just make a method as are the other ones

Comment: it is not yet part of the language, use babel.

Comment: a class method can’t be a lambda as far as i recall

Comment: What browser/environment are you using?

Answer (score 3):

its not yet part of the language , use babel

or

```
class Tree {   
  constructor(rootNode) {
    this._rootNode = rootNode;
    rootNode.makeRoot();

    // bind `this` in the constructor
    this.findNode = this.findNode.bind(this)
    this.findNodeWithID = this.findNodeWithID.bind(this)
    this.getRoot = this.getRoot.bind(this)
}

getRoot() {
    return this._rootNode;
}

findNodeWithID(id) {
   return this.findNode(this._rootNode, id);
}

findNode(node, id){
    if(node.id === id) {
        return node;
    } else {
        node.getChildren().forEach(child => {
              this.findNode(child, id);
        });
    } 
    return null;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to use arrow functions as class property you need to add  transform-class-properties plugin as is explained 
[here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31362292/how-to-use-arrow-functions-public-class-fields-as-class-methods)

Comment: Please vote or flag as duplicate in such a case.

Answer (score 0):

If you want `findNode` to be in the prototype of Tree, either use a regular function:

```
class Tree {
  …
  findNode(node, id) {
    …
  }
}
```

Or assign it directly to the prototype:

```
Tree.prototype.findNode = (node, id) => {…}
```

If you want findNode to be initialized as a property, do it in the constructor:

```
class Tree {
  constructor() {
    this.findNode = (node, id) => {…}
  }
  …
}
```

Or utilize TypeScript, which will allow the syntax you are using.

As you are referencing `this` in the function, you don’t want it to be an arrow function, as it will not have `this` context