# Webpack not building ES6 class missing config issue

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

I am having an issue adding webpack to an existing React project. Previously, the project was rendered server-side with next.js. However, there seems to be something wrong with my webpack config. Whenever I try to build my project, it fails with seemingly valid ES6 code:

ERROR in ./src/components/shared/menu/component.js
    Module build failed: SyntaxError: Unexpected token (8:12)

```
   6 |
   7 | export default class Menu extends PureComponent {
>  8 |   propTypes = {
     |             ^
   9 |     items: PropTypes.arrayOf(PropTypes.shape({
  10 |       name: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  11 |       action: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
```

My webpack.config.js

```
    const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
    entry: './src/pages/index/index.js',
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
        filename: 'bundle.js'
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            { 
                test: /\.js?$/, 
                loader: 'babel-loader', 
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                query: {
                    presets: ['es2015', 'react']
                  }           
            },
            {
                test: /\.scss$/,
                use: [ 
                    "style-loader", // creates style nodes from JS strings
                    "css-loader", // translates CSS into CommonJS
                    "sass-loader" // compiles Sass to CSS
                 ]
            }
        ]
    },
    devServer: {
        contentBase: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist")
    }
};
```

My .babelrc

```
{ "presets": ["es2015", "react"] }
```

I've already tried search on SO and google, but cannot find anyone else experiencing the same issue. Please advise! Thanks!

Comment: If there is nothing like babel, typescript, etc, you can't do properties like that in pure ES6.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use arrow functions (public class fields) as class methods?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31362292/how-to-use-arrow-functions-public-class-fields-as-class-methods)

Comment: @ASDFGerte clearly OP is using babel

Comment: FYI, field declarations are not valid ES6, it's a stage 3 proposal currently, https://github.com/tc39/proposal-class-fields

Answer (score 1):

1) run: `npm install --save-dev babel-plugin-transform-class-properties`

2) Update your `.babelrc` file:

`{ "presets": ["es2015", "react"], "plugins": ["transform-class-properties"] }`

That way, babel will also transform class properties as specified in the README: https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-plugin-transform-class-properties

Also, make sure to use the keyword `static` when you define `propTypes` inside a class (so that it will be declared on the class itself, not on its prototype)

Comment: Thanks, that took care of the error. Getting some problems with the spread operator now. Adding "transform-es2015-destructuring" and "transform-object-rest-spread" to my babel plugins should address the problem, right?

Comment: Based on your comment, you will most likelly need the following plugins: `["transform-class-properties", "transform-es2015-destructuring", "transform-object-rest-spread", "add-module-exports"]`

Answer (score -1):

Use babel polyfill plugin, and have it included in webpack before your entry points, that means have entry point as array and first elemen is 'babel-polyfill' and second element is your index.js

You could also have require or import babel-polyfill as the first line index.js but only needed to have it once either in webpack or index file.

Comment: `babel-polyfill` has other purposes like making sure `Array#includes()` will be available (provide a polyfill if necessary) - `create-react-app@1.x.x` uses `babel-plugin-transform-class-properties` in its config https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/v1.1.4/packages/babel-preset-react-app/package.json#L16