# Why methods as arrow functions work in react classes but not in normal classes?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, es6-class, arrow-functions

We can declare methods of component class as arrow functions, like so:

```
class SomeComponent extends React.Component {
  someMethod = () => { // <<----- This does not throw error
    // some code
  }
}
```

..that won't throw any error, but below does:

```
class SomeNormalClass {
  someMethod = () => { // <<----- This throws error
    // some code
  }
}
```

It says unexpected `=` after `someMethod`. It works fine if I change my `someMethod` back to normal function instead of declaring it as an arrow function as shown below. Why?

```
class SomeNormalClass {
  function someMethod() { // <<----- This works fine
    // some code
  }
}
```

Comment: Related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31362292/how-to-use-arrow-functions-public-class-fields-as-class-methods

Comment: *This works fine* - this is invalid code that will result in syntax error. `function` keyword is out of place. The question lacks https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: It has nothing to do with React but with the build tool you are (or are not) using.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `someMethod` in first example is a property of the class, not a method. BabelJS support properties in classes, but native js not.
You can see difference [here](https://babeljs.io/repl#?babili=false&browsers=&build=&builtIns=false&spec=false&loose=false&code_lz=MYGwhgzhAEAqCmEAu0DeAoaAHATgey3hyQE9oBeaACgEoKA-aYPAOwjxHgDoQ8BzKgEYaAbmiZ2AW3gBZeEgAWeACbU6GaNACQzNh268BSHAFd4o8dAC-6K0A&debug=false&forceAllTransforms=false&shippedProposals=false&circleciRepo=&evaluate=false&fileSize=false&timeTravel=false&sourceType=module&lineWrap=true&presets=es2016%2Creact%2Cstage-2&prettier=false&targets=&version=6.26.0&envVersion=). You should add some properties in `constructor` for Vanilla JS.

Answer (score 0):

`someMethod = () => {...}` is class field. Class fields are [stage 3 proposal](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-class-fields) which isn't natively supported and needs to be transformed by transpiler (Babel); `someMethod` class field is syntactic sugar for constructor code:

```
constructor() {
  this.someMethod = () => {
    // some code
  }
}
```

[Both `SomeComponent` and `SomeNormalClass` are expected to work](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-6pgj4d) when used in same conditions. Neither of them will work natively.