# What is the point of wrapping a function of react component if i want to pass it down as a property?

Tags: javascript, eventhandler

What is the point of this? 
In the next example i found in book code we have a funtion in the component that changes component state createTimer()

```
createTimer = (timer) => 
{
   const t = helpers.newTimer(timer);
   this.setState({
     timers: this.state.timers.concat(t),
   });

   client.createTimer(t);   
};
```

It is wrapped:

```
handleCreateFormSubmit = (timer) => {
this.createTimer(timer); };
```

And passed down as property:

```
<ToggleableTimerForm
onFormSubmit={this.handleCreateFormSubmit}
/>
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/q/20279484/1048572 and https://stackoverflow.com/q/31362292/1048572

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just do this:

```
<ToggleableTimerForm onFormSubmit={this.createTimer}/>
```

...and `createTimer` is a regular method of your class:

```
class YourComponent extends Component {
  createTimer(timer) {
    const t = helpers.newTimer(timer);
    this.setState({
      timers: this.state.timers.concat(t),
    });

    client.createTimer(t);
  }
}
```

...then the issue would be that when the child component calls `onFormSubmit`, `this` wouldn't be set correctly.

But since you're setting a *property* of your *instance* and are using an arrow function:

```
class YourComponent extends Component {
  createTimer = (timer) => {
    const t = helpers.newTimer(timer);
    this.setState({
      timers: this.state.timers.concat(t),
    });

    client.createTimer(t);   
  };
}
```

...you don't have to worry about `this` being bound correctly, so you're right that you *don't* need the wrapper to fix that. Perhaps the wrapping function is there as a precautionary measure since the class method pattern is more common.

The only benefit you'd gain is if the child calls `this.props.onFormSubmit` with additional arguments that you want to ignore. If that's not the case, then you can leave out the wrapping function.

Comment: What if i won't declare createTimer as arrow function but declare it as a simple function that require binding to class, should i wrap it and pass to property wrapper?

Comment: @BashLord: if you bind it to the instance with, say `this.createTimer = this.createTimer.bind(this);`, then you don't need to wrap it since no matter how it's called, `this` will be established properly.

Answer (score 0):

Generally you pass a function down that's bound to it's original component. This allows child components to alter the state of their parent. Imagine this Scenario :

I have a parent component with state property A. I have a function that takes an input and updates the state of the PARENT!!!!
I pass that as a prop to a child (maybe a form). When I submit the form, I call the function passed as a prop to update the PARENTS state with my form values.

A few things to keep in mind, lexical arrow functions **LACK SCOPE**, and if the function leverages the state of the component it must be bound to the component.

One problem I see in your code....

`handleCreateFormSubmit` requires a parameter. `onFormSubmit` will pas it one, but I don't think it'll be the one you're expecting. It'll pass the event. You can do something along these lines "

`onFormSubmit={() => this.handleCreateFormSubmit(someValue)}`