# Why is the method called in the constructor of my class not working as expected?

Tags: javascript, constructor

This is a part of my class `Bird`:

```
class Bird
{
    constructor()
    {
        this.imagePaths = ['./assets/Bill-Gates.png', './assets/steve-jobs.png', './assets/zuckerberg.png'];
        this.elementImg.src = this.changeImage();
        this.speed = Math.floor((Math.random() * 5) + 5);
    }
```

In the class's constructor, I want to react to different speeds and assign different images to the object:

```
changeImage = () => {
    if (this.speed < 6) {
        return this.imagePaths[0];
    }
    else if (this.speed < 9) {
        return this.imagePaths[1];
    }
    else if (this.speed > 9) {
        return this.imagePaths[2];
    }
}
```

I try to do this by assigning the images to the `elementImg.src` property via a method. But the method does not return the desired value. Why?

Comment: This is an English-language site, are you able to translate your German to English in order to better assist those of us that don't speak German to help you?

Comment: What is the problem with that code? Are you getting an error?

Comment: what is the question here?

Comment: I guess you have to assign `this.speed` before you use it in the method, so just move the `this.speed = ` line one up.

Answer (score 2):

in a Class the functions look like this:

```
changeImage(){
    if (this.speed < 6) {
        return this.imagePaths[0];
    } else if (this.speed < 9) {
        return this.imagePaths[1];
    } else if (this.speed > 9) {
        return this.imagePaths[2];
    }
}
```

If that was the question?

Here is the full Code which should work.

```
class Bird {
    constructor() {
        this.imagePaths = ['./assets/Bill-Gates.png', './assets/steve-jobs.png', './assets/zuckerberg.png'];
        this.speed = Math.floor((Math.random() * 5) + 5);
        this.elementImg.src = this.changeImage();
    }
    changeImage(){
        if (this.speed < 6) {
            return this.imagePaths[0];
        } else if (this.speed < 9) {
            return this.imagePaths[1];
        } else if (this.speed > 9) {
            return this.imagePaths[2];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: after I change the method like this he gives me this error "Expected to return a value at the end of method 'changeImage' ".

Comment: if it doesn't return a value, then "this.speed" is 9.
You don't have a case for that.

Comment: Um, `changeImage = () => { }` is actually [valid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31362292/how-to-use-arrow-functions-public-class-fields-as-class-methods), the real answer is the other change you have made...

Comment: @h.solo thats a linter hint, not an error, so you can safely ignore it (as it doesnt cause any problems here)

Comment: @Jonas Wilms, thanks for the hint. I didn't know that as well. 
But since I didn't understand the question at first, I thought it was what he asked for :-)

Comment: @JonasWilms: `() => {}` is not valid in this case because arrow function statically bind `this` upon declaration therefore the `this` in changeImage will be different form the one created in the constructor (which will only exist when the the constructor is called, not when changeImage is defined)

Comment: @slebetman wrong. class fields are initialized after the constructor, and are bound to the instances context

Comment: @JonasWilms Then `() => {}` would not be valid in this case because class fields are processed after constructor call therefore it's `this` will not exist at the time the constructor is called. Even the function would not exist at the time the constructor is called

Comment: @JonasWilms: Also, I didn't think javascript classes can have fields/properties? Do you have documentation for how that would work? MDN doesn't mention anything about properties. JS classes can only have methods according to most docs I read. You are supposed to declare instance properties inside the constructor and this include functions, not just numbers and strings

Comment: @slebetman if you would click on the link above you would see that it is a "proposal", to be found [here](https://tc39.github.io/proposal-class-public-fields/), and i was wrong, class fields are initialized before the constructor is executed (apologies, I haven't used them much yet)

Comment: So now I've tested it myself and `changeImage = () => { }` throws `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token =`

Comment: @andre cause its a proposal (!!) you have to use Babel or tsc to compile it down to ES7.

Comment: In which case, even if the proposal were to be approved it's not a good idea to use arrow functions in classes. While it would work for the constructor it would make the method uninheritable

Comment: @slebetman It is actually a really good idea, class properties are inherited. It resolves the "class method as a callback" problem, e.g. `setTimeout(this.remove, 100)`

Comment: @JonasWilms For classes you never intend to inherit yes. But arrow functions breaks the functionality of `this`. Therefore you cannot inherit from the class afterwards.

Comment: @slebetman what?! I have no idea what you are talking about. I guess you should play a but with class fields to understand their usage.