# Use ECMAScript 6 arrow functions as class methods

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, arrow-functions

I'm testing my code with node v8.9.4

I want to use class methods in my promises chain. But this fails with an error:
`(node:68487) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): TypeError: Cannot read property 'attr' of undefined`

```
const fsp = require('fs-promise');

class MyClass {
    constructor() {
        this.attr = 'value';
    }

    promiseMe() {
        console.log(this.attr);
    }

    main() {
        fsp.readdir('.').then(this.promiseMe);
    }
}

new MyClass().main();
```

So I try to use arrow functions as class methods.
But defining an arrow function as a class method is syntactically not correct:
`Unexpected token =`

```
promiseMe = () =>  {
    console.log(this.attr);
}
```

This works, but it is really ugly:

```
const fsp = require('fs-promise');

class MyClass {
    constructor() {
        this.attr = 'value';
        this.promiseMe = () => {console.log(this.attr);}
    }

    main() {
        this.promiseMe();
    }
}

new MyClass().main();
```

**So how can I use class methods in promises?**

There is another question regarding this topic:
[How to use arrow functions (public class fields) as class methods?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31362292/how-to-use-arrow-functions-public-class-fields-as-class-methods)
Unfortunately this doesn't work with my node.js setup.

Comment: Arrow functions as methods won't get `this` properly set when they are invoked.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use arrow functions (public class fields) as class methods?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31362292/how-to-use-arrow-functions-public-class-fields-as-class-methods)

Comment: *"I want to use class methods in my promises chain."* -> `somePromise.then(someClass.someMethod.bind(someClass))` for a "class method" or `somePromise.then(someInstance.someMethod.bind(someInstance))` for an "instance method"

Comment: Note you could also use `fsp.readdir('.').then(x => this.promiseMe(x))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right this is because your context is incorrect within your Promise. One method is to bind `this` to your Promise context. In your example you would call it like `fsp.readdir('.').then(this.promiseMe.bind(this));`

Alternatively, if you're using this more often, you can bind it in your constructor:

```
this.promiseMe = this.promiseMe.bind(this)
```

This will bind it in your class so that you no longer need to bind every time you call!

Answer (score 0):

> An arrow function expression has a shorter syntax than a function
>   expression and does not have its own this, arguments, super, or
>   new.target. These function expressions are best suited for non-method
>   functions, and they cannot be used as constructors.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions

You are getting `TypeError: Cannot read property 'attr' of undefined` because `this` is not referencing your class instance.

Comment: I understand that problem. But how can I use my class method in my promises then?

Comment: you can set this in a variable and use that variable as a this like `let ref = this;` before arrow function

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you've already figured out what options you have when it comes to the `class` syntax. But I suggest that you ask yourself the whether the `class` syntax/mechanism is actually providing something you need.

It may well be the case that you can accomplish everything you need by using a factory function. This avoids all the ugly quirks of using `this`:

```
const fsp = require('fs-promise');

function myClass() {
    let attr = 'value';

    const promiseMe = () => console.log(attr);
    const main = () => fsp.readdir('.').then(promiseMe);

    return { promiseMe, main };
}

myClass().main();
```