# access 'this' inside d3 call back with angular 7

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

i have a following code inside angular directive, i wanted to access class level variable inside the call back function so i used the arrow function but the 'this' is still not pointing to directive.

```
this.itemRects.selectAll('rect')
            .data(this.visItems, (d) => {
                return d.id + this.x;
            })
```

i added debugger at the return statement[image] on the debugger it shows this pointing towards data array.

how can i access directive level 'this' inside callback function?

Comment: Is code this inside another arrow function? You could try to do let self = this; and then use self instead of this.

Comment: the code is inside the class level function

Answer (score 3):

In the call back function , this refers to callback function object. you can declare a variable outside of callback function like this:

```
var self = this;
```

and access class variables in call back function using self, instead of this.

Please check below link to bind class variables in call back function using arrow symbol: [How to use arrow functions (public class fields) as class methods?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31362292/how-to-use-arrow-functions-public-class-fields-as-class-methods)

Try:

```
this.itemRects.selectAll('rect')
            .data(this.visItems, (d,x) => {
                return d.id + x;
            })
```

Comment: i am using arrow functions ,shouldn't i be able to access 'this' without using the variable?