# Using arrow function in Javascript Protractor test automation framework

Tags: javascript, protractor, babeljs, arrow-functions

I wanna use a method like below with arrow functions:

```
clickElement = element => element.click();
```

Instead of a code like below:

```
clickElement(element) {
    return element.click();
}
```

But i am getting a syntax error under the first equal sign. How can i resolve that and use arrow function? Could anyone please advice. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Where is this function written? Inside a class, object, another function?

Comment: use like this: const clickElement = element => element.click();

Comment: @adiga - the function is inside a class

Comment: @Sunil tc - When i use 'const', i am getting the error as - "'const' can only be used in a .ts file". I am not using Typescript.

Comment: Why do you want to convert to an arrow function? `clickElement(element) {}` will add the function to the class prototype. Whereas `clickElement = element => element.click()` will create a [class field](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-class-fields). You need to enable the feature since it is not widely supported as of now. Please go through this: [How to use arrow functions (public class fields) as class methods?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31362292)

Comment: Can you add complete code to know whether it's inside any class or fucntion ?

Comment: What IDE are you using? I think it's a lint error, try to see if your eslint/jslint is set correctly(probably has been set below ES2015).

Comment: You still have this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Assign the function to a variable.

```
const clickElement = element => element.click();
```

Comment: `clickElement` doesn't have a `function` keyword. So, this is either inside a class or an object where `const` will not work

Comment: @adiga Arrow function does not need function keyword.

Comment: I meant OP's working code `clickElement(element) {
    return element.click();
}`

Comment: I just wanted to implement arrow function to simplify the code. How can i do that? When i use 'const', i am getting the error as - "'const' can only be used in a .ts file". I am not using Typescript.

Comment: @AravindanK they are completely different things. Arrow function will be added to each instance of the class. With your existing syntax, it will be added only to `yourClass.prototype.clickElement`. If you still want to use arrow, you need to enable the feature: [How to use arrow functions (public class fields) as class methods?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31362292)

Comment: you just need variable to keep the function: var clickElement = element => element.click();

Comment: @AravindanK Can you give some more information to know exactly whats the issue?

Comment: @Suniltc this has nothing to do with adding `const` or `var`

Comment: Thanks @adiga i will check the link that you have shared.

Comment: Even after using - npm install --save-dev babel-plugin-transform-class-properties and 
npm install --save-dev @babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties, i am not able to use arrow functions

Comment: Do i really need to use arrows, or this is fine? clickElement(element) {
    return element.click();
}

Comment: @AravindanK that is fine and I'd actually recommend it over arrow. If you add class fields, it will be added to each instance.

Answer (score -1):

try it like this?

```
const clickElement = (element) => element.click();
```

Call it like this:

```
clickElement(someElement);
```