# Is there anyway to get rid of binding `this` to `Component` functions in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

This is what I do when I want to make `this` of my class functions bind to the class (component) instance. Is there any easier/more proper way to do this in React?

```
class App extends Component {

  state = {
    currentSection: 1,
    message :{text:''}
  };

 
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.prevSection = this.prevSection.bind(this);
    this.nextSection = this.nextSection.bind(this);
    this.mobileChanged = this.mobileChanged.bind(this);
  }
}
```

Comment: Another alternative is not to use classes. Then you can avoid usage of `this`. Using bind as you have done will make the methods available on the prototype. If you don't care if the methods are accessible until after the constructor has been called, use an arrow function. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31362292/how-to-use-arrow-functions-public-class-fields-as-class-methods

Answer (score 2):

If I recall correctly, if you change:

```
function nextSection() {...}
```

to

```
const nextSection = () => {...}
```

After this change, you can remove `this` and the `bind`

Please let me know if your component will remain as functional like it was before. I'm not sure if it this will change the behaviour.

Comment: Actually, there must not include the `const` but just `nextSection = () => {...}`. Just like you, I've been giving up on the class component so long that I've nearly forgotten how to write it. ;)

Answer (score 2):

**You could use `arrow function` instead of class method**

With [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions), there will be no `this context` so you won't have to bind it

```
class App extends Component {
  state = {
    currentSection: 1,
    message: { text: '' },
  };

  prevSection = () => {}

  nextSection = () => {}

  mobileChanged = () => {}
}
```

Live example:

[image: Edit boring-ramanujan-rnrx0]

Comment: So which practice is better? Making use of easy class functions and binding vs. arrow functions?

Comment: @Ehsan88 any is fine. If possible you can avoid using class components.

Comment: @Ehsan88 It's not much of a difference to be a concern, you would rather priority more `human-readable` code than that.