# Unhandled Runtime Error => TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'setState')

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ethereum

I ran into this Runtime error which says setState is undefined as I tried to connect to my Rinkeby test network on Metamask. I have tried binding using constructor props but that is not working. I am at loss what to do. Here's my code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { Button, Form, Input, Grid, Message } from 'semantic-ui-react'
import Layout from '../../components/Layout'
import factory from '../../ethereum/factory'
import web3 from '../../ethereum/web3'
import { Router } from '../../routes'

class New extends React.Component {


constructor(props) {
super(props);
this.state = {
    minimumContribution: '',
    errorMessage: '',
    loading: false
  }
this.onSubmit = this.onSubmit.bind(this);
  }

onSubmit = async event => {
event.preventDefault()
const accounts = await web3.eth.getAccounts()
this.setState({ loading: true, errorMessage: '' })

try {
  await factory.methods.createCampaign(this.state.minimumContribution).send({
    from: accounts[0]
  });

  Router.pushRoute('/')
} catch (error) {
  this.setState({ errorMessage: error.message })
}
this.setState({ loading: false })
}

render() {
const { errorMessage, loading } = this.state
return (
  <Layout>
    <Grid centered columns={2}>
      <Grid.Column>
        <h3>Create a Campaign.</h3>
        <Form onSubmit={this.onSubmit} error={!!errorMessage}>
          <Form.Field>
            <lable>Minimum Contribution </lable>
            <Input
              label="WEI"
              labelPosition="right"
              value={this.state.minimumContribution}
              onChange={event=>this.setState({minimumContribution:event.target.value})}
            />
          </Form.Field>
          <Message error header="Oops!" content={errorMessage}/>
          <Button loading={loading} primary>Create</Button>
        </Form>
      </Grid.Column>
    </Grid>
  </Layout>
    )
   }
  }

  export default New
```

If it does help I am following an ethereum course on Udemy (Ethereum and Solidity: The Complete Developer's Guide). The error occurs at lecture 190.

Comment: What line does the error occur on?

Comment: Does it happen as soon as the page loads, or when a specific action happens? I'm wondering if it is your Input onChange configuration. If you comment it out, does it work? I will try it myself when I'm in front of a computer.

Comment: The error occurs at this.setState({loading: true, errorMessage: ''})

Answer (score 0):

You should use `async onSubmit (event) {` and not `onSubmit = async event => {`.

The former declares a method while the latter initializes a class property with an arrow function. Arrow functions don't have their own `this` (and no, binding won't change that) so the surrounding scope's `this` will be used, which will be the global scope (the `class` block isn't a scope per se as it cannot contain code), and the global scope's `this` is `undefined`, and therefore, your code currently crashes on accessing `this.setState`.

Comment: Or you can also use `const onSubmit = async (event) => { //code here }`

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the 'this' context is being lost.

add a new method using arrow function

```
handleChange = event => this.setState({minimumContribution:event.target.value})
```

Refer that function in onChange

```
onChange={this.handleChange}
```

Answer (score 0):

remove `this.onSubmit = this.onSubmit.bind(this);` from the constructor if you want to use class properties.
for more information, see
[How to use arrow functions (public class fields) as class methods?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31362292/how-to-use-arrow-functions-public-class-fields-as-class-methods)