# Using `this` in a destructured method

Tags: javascript

Say I have a class like this:

```
class MyClass {
    prop = []; 
    method() { 
        return this.prop.length; 
    }
}
```

Then I create an instance:

```
let myInstance = new MyClass();
```

Then I destructure it:

```
let { prop, method } = myInstance;
```

And finally try to call `method` then the browser complains that `this` is undefined:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'prop')

Is there some syntax I can work into my class to allow me to use destructured method?

Comment: The problem is not with taking the method out of the object (well, of the prototype), it fails when you *call* it because there's no way for the proper `this` value to be known. You can use `method.call(myInstance)`, or you can use `.bind()` to create a new wrapper function that will effectively do that for you.

Comment: You could always use [arrow function methods](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31362350/283366) however this isn't the same since the `method` would no longer be part of the class prototype

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a way yes, but the class has to know what methods it is providing that can be called without specifying its `this` value, such as when the **instance method needs  to be passed as a callback function** of some kind. One possibility is for the constructor of the instance to bind the method to the instance object:

```js
class MyClass {
    constructor() {
        this.method = this.method.bind(this);
    }
    props = [];
    method() {
        return this.props.length;
   }
}
```