# What is the difference between declaring a class using class constructor vs regular function

Tags: javascript, class, prototypal-inheritance

Is there any difference between the two methods of setting up a class in javascript:

**Example 1:**

```
class Friend {
  constructor(name) {
    this.name = name;
  }
}

var friendOne = new Friend('John');
```

**Example 2:**

```
function Friend(name){
  this.name = name;
}

var friendOne = new Friend('John');
```

**Both of these examples create:**

```
// Friend.prototype
// {constructor: ƒ}
```

So my question is related to what approach is best for creating class based inheritance with Javascript?

Thanks

Comment: This gets asked a lot, for example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36099721/javascript-what-is-the-difference-between-function-and-class

Comment: Perfect. I will review this. That is what I needed.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript: What is the difference between Function and Class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36099721/javascript-what-is-the-difference-between-function-and-class)

Answer (score 0):

I think there is no obvious differences for them.
compare with "Function" constructor, "class" just syntax sugar, more semantic.

Comment: Aaron, I see what your saying, but check out the link that @Ray Toal just posted... there are some other things aside from the "sugar"

Comment: That link mostly talk about differences of specification.