# Why can't I substitute a class's prototype with another class's?

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

Given two classes where I want to give the methods of one to another:

```
class a {}
class b {say() {console.log('hello')}}
var foo = new a();
```

How come this works:

```
a.prototype.say = b.prototype.say;
foo.say();    //'hello'
```

But this doesn't?

```
a.prototype = b.prototype;
foo.say();    //foo.say is not a function
```

To be clear, I'm not asking *how* to give one class's methods to another, but *why* prototype behaves like this.

Bonus question: what's the difference between defining a method inside a class block and defining it by directly assigning it to the prototype?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reason for this is that `prototype` on a class is a non-writable, non-configurable property:

```js
class a {}
class b {say() {console.log('hello')}}

console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(a,'prototype'))
```

Non-writable means you can't reassign the property `prototype` and non-configurable means you can't change the property to make `writable: true` or delete the property.

The result is that this has no effect:

```js
class a {}
class b {say() {console.log('hello')}}

a.prototype = b.prototype;
console.log(a.prototype === b.prototype)
```

But non-writable only means you can't change the value associate with the property `a.prototype` — it will always point to the same object — it doesn't mean that you can't add properties to that object. This is why you can still add `a.prototype.say`.

Comment: Also worth adding, this differs slightly from declaring `function a(){}` and `function b(){}` where `a.prototype = b.prototype` would actually change the prototype property.

Comment: @zzzzBov That's pretty interesting. Are there other differences are there between a javascript "class" and a function? Even though they're supposed to be the same thing internally.

Comment: @leinaD_natipaC, they're not supposed to be the same thing. `class` is syntactic sugar for a bunch of common best-practices for creating constructors and prototypes, so it essentially adds a lot of boilerplate behind-the-scenes that can be duplicated if one chooses to do so.

Comment: @zzzzBov That's the best description of js class vs function I've seen yet. I've searched for class vs function, [found a decent stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36102080/1730082). It seems like indeed the differences are mostly a bit of boilerplate and things you can and can't do inside the class definition. If I declared `a` as a function and *then* did `a.prototype = b.prototype`, can I expect `a` to behave exactly like `b` other than having a reassignable prototype?

Comment: @leinaD_natipaC simply assigning the prototype from `b` to `a` won't make the function `a` do the same thing as `b`. `a` and `b` will still be totally different functions with different behavior when called — in other words `a()` and `b()` might do totally different things.

Comment: @MarkMeyer Point taken, but I mean other than that, for example if `a` has no function body and `b` has no constructor, would they be the same thing then? Or would there be subtle distinctions like one having a mutable prototype vs the other one not?